# Using .htaccess to redirect traffic cause redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect users to an a different url when they access my webapp from a particular url. For example, if they use `192.0.2.4:80` to visit the web app, I want to redirect them to `192.0.2.5:8989`.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://192.0.2.4:80$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.0.2.5:8989$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I access the site using `192.0.2.4:80` it redirect to `192.0.2.5:8989` but it repeatedly concatenates it in the URL bar. For example:

`192.0.2.5:8989/192.0.2.5:8989/192.0.2.5:8989/192.0.2.5:8989` etc.

I also get the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Comment: Whilst this would create a redirect-loop, by itself this won't result in the redirect-loop as stated, unless there is an additional conflict with other directives (or you were seeing a cached response)?

Comment: 1) Are you sure your users access your website with an URL containing an IP address? While technically ok, this is not the usual case. 2) Since HTTP_HOST is, by its name, the `host` header in the HTTP request, which is only the hostname part of the URL and not the full URL, your `RewriteCond` will always be true as HTTP_HOST will never be the string `http://192.0.2.4:80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192.0.2.4:80$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://192.0.2.5:8989 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT**

As suggested below by MrWhite, the above redirect only redirects the root. The below redirect will redirect all sub directories.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^13.210.137.143$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.0.2.5:8989/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Although this only redirects the document root - is that the intention? Strictly speaking, you should also append a trailing slash, after the hostname+port - otherwise you are reliant on the user-agent appending the slash on the redirected request.

Comment: @MrWhite I did not consider that, I have added a trailing slash to the end of both address but only the document root is being redirected. Any advice?

Comment: You would need the `RewriteRule` directive you had initially (in your question) - but with the slash. ie. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.0.2.5:8989/$1 [L,R=301]`